# ValueError: Shapes (16,) and (1, 16) are not compatible in tensorflow1.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I run the following code in tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_input_data = np.random.random((1024,16))
q = tf.train.input_producer(x_input_data, element_shape=[1,16])
input = q.dequeue() # It replaces our input placeholder
print (x_input_data.shape)
print (input.get_shape())

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
example_batch = tf.train.batch([input], batch_size=1024, num_threads=4, capacity=40, enqueue_many=True)
for step in range(1000):
    sess.run(example_batch)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: Shapes (16,) and (1, 16) are not compatible
```

Why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/input_producer, element_shape is the shape of a row which refers to a 1D numpy array `(16,)` as opposed to the 2D numpy array supplied, `(1, 16)`. If you remove element_shape or replace it with `(16,) it should work.

Comment: If i set [16,] in the element_shape i get the following error: `ValueError: Inputs to Dense should have rank >= 2.` Its refer to this line of my model function: `layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=example_batch, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)`

Comment: Can you use `tf.expand_dims` to expand example_batch so it has a rank of 2?

Comment: I use the following code: `tf.expand_dims(input, 1) print (input.get_shape())` and the output is `(16,)` and I get again `ValueError: Inputs to Dense should have rank >= 2.`